# How does a component know to re-render when prop changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We know that a React component will re-render when props or state changes (assuming `shouldComponentUpdate()` not blocked).

My question is: how does React know the component's props has changed and will therefore need a re-render? How does it happen?

For state, all mutations are done by through `setState()` so at least I can see the mechanism, but for props, it all seems magical.

Comment: Are you wondering how the comparison is made between an old vs new prop, or how the check is triggered?

Comment: There is a virtual Dom created for every component we create with states/props and this virtual Dom is there to compare. when there is a change in the value it updates the view.

Comment: The only way a prop will change is when a parent component is re-rendered. During a component's render, React will propagate the changes down through the tree to anything which has a prop change.

Comment: Maybe this article would be useful: [Why and How to Use PureComponent in React.js](https://60devs.com/pure-component-in-react.html)